Book about a human woman sent to an alien prison planet
It’s about a human woman who is sent to an alien prison planet and MMC figures that he wants her but she runs away from him and hides on the planet. She’s hidden for ages and he gets annoyed he can’t find her by scent (turns out she is covering herself in something gross). Then she decides to wear this helmet and pretend to be a male alien. They ask her to take off the helmet but she says that she has bad scarring and so they let her keep it on and so they think it’s a male alien. She then meets the MMC again and they become friends because he thinks she is a guy.
There is also something about her being some kind of scientist, which is why they let her into their settlement in the first place.
There is also a scene at the start where he catches her playing with herself in a pool and that’s when she first runs from him.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

I think I read it within the last year or so, not sure where, probably online. I’ve been searching everywhere for this book and cannot find it

Was it a softcover? Hardcover? Kindle? PDF?
